# Where is Jetbrains config file for Resource Root?

Tags: webstorm

I'd like to commit my Webstorm config because I use absolute import path and my Resource Root is `/src` not `/`.

The feature is working fine, but I don't find the config file in the `.idea` where the path is defined.

I tried to make a search with `src` keyword, but I found nothing.

My question is: where is the config file for Resource Root folder in Jetbrains solutions ?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's in `.idea\webResources.xml`:

```
<entryData>
          <resourceRoots>
            <path value="file://$PROJECT_DIR$/public" />
            <path value="file://$PROJECT_DIR$/assets" />
             ...
          </resourceRoots>
</entryData>
```